# Multiple threading questions when using sqlite transaction in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I use sqlite transaction in Android:

```
SQLiteDatabase database = sqlite_helper.getWritableDatabase();

database.beginTransaction();
...
database.setTransactionSuccessful();
database.endTransaction();
```

My questions are :
1. Should I place `endTransaction()` in finally code block like this：

```
try {
    database.beginTransaction();
    ...
    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
finally {
    database.endTransaction();
}
```

If there are exepctions during database operations, will the database be rolled back automatically without using "finally"?

1. When the transaction is not ended, can other threads read or write the same database? I hear sqlite in Android is threading safe, but I are not sure with it. I guess there will be some problems during transaction. Is there an error raised if another thread writes the same database with the same connection?
   I ever found this error in my app, but I don't know whether it's related to the threading safe problem:

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteMisuseException: library routine called out of sequence:`

, while compiling

Does anyone help me to answer these questions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.you should always place endTransaction in finally block

2.transaction in SQLite  is thread safe,see the doc http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html

Comment: The link has no mentioning of the word 'thread'. How is it thread-safe? The question is if another thread would create a new transaction OR run a new query while a transaction from another thread is open. Is it thread-safe then? In my current experience I get weird 'connection-pool' errors.

Comment: Transactions are **not** thread-safe. There is only one ``SQLiteDatabase`` instance shared between threads, and hence the database can only be in one transaction state which will be manipulated by two threads concurrently. If one thread begins a transaction, and then a second thread attempts to begin another transaction, you will get an IllegalStateException thrown up.

Comment: The Android beginTransaction and endTransaction are thread-safe wrapper functions around the actual BEGIN and COMMIT commands using Java synchronisation, even though it internally uses a single database connection. If you're using the native SQLite API directly (unlikely in Android), it's *not* thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

You should always put `endTransaction()` into a `finally` block (also see [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29)).
Otherwise, the database would not be able to notice than an exception has happened.

The only other way to end a transaction would be to close the connection, in which case SQLite automatically rolls back any active transaction.

As long as one connection writes to the database (which means that a transaction is active), no other connections can read or write. Therefore, you should take care not to forget to end transactions.

You should never write from multiple threads; what would happen if one threads ends the transaction while the other one is still writing?

Your `SQLiteMisuseException` might be related, or not; that's impossible to say without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use the finally block.  Here is a simple, THREAD SAFE method I use:

```
/**
 * Call for multiple DB insertion transactions.  It is thread safe and fast!
 */
private synchronized void writeTransaction(Runnable task) {
    try {
        db.beginTransaction();
        task.run();
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

the *synchronized* keyword locks the method with its containing object, thus making it thread safe...